# SQL Server 2000 incorrect message: duplicate key with unique index

Tags: sql-server

Database server: SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.760 - SP3 - Standard Edition

I have a table with 5 columns, in which I want to add a large (300.000) number of records. There is a unique index on the combination of two columns. If I add the records with this unique index in place, SQL Server gives this error message:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 3, Line 1
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'TESTTABLE' with unique index 'test'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)

However, if I delete the unique index and then add the records, I do not get any error when I create this unique index afterwards.

Comment: What are using to add the records?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 9.00.2047.00
- an insert query which selects records from a table on a different server joined by a table in the same database containing the table I wanted to add the >300k records to.

Answer (score 0):

Check which fields constitute your unique index.

You have duplication in your source data on those fields which is causing your INSERT to fail.

What you do about that depends on the nature of your data.  If it's just that one row is newer than other, making the original obsolete, then you can get rid.  Otherwise, speak to your business people about :-

- what you should do with the dupe data
- whether the unique constraint on the 
  columns is necessary

Some problems can be solved easily.  For this one, most of your solutions are actually non-technical.

Comment: As far as I know I have no duplicate data in the records I want to add. Because if I add the records without this index in place, I get no error message, and I can add this unique index after I have added the records. But I cannot add the records when I have first created the unique index!

Answer (score 0):

One of your assumptions has to be wrong.  Re-visit them.  Either the nature of your index, the data coming in, the pre-existing data (if any), the collation (case-insensitive/case-sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraint (not index) that uses WITH NOCHECK in the [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462(SQL.80).aspx)?